# "ORA-01843: Not a vaild month" when comparing insert_date to String

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table that uses sysdate to assign column "insert_date" the current date and time upon inserting records into the table. I'm trying to use a query to check for records depending on the day they were inserted:

```
select insert_date
from integration.ol_order
where trunc(insert_date) like '%5/1/2015%'
```

Upon running the query, I get "ORA-01843: Not a vaild month" even though trunc(insert_date) outputs '5/1/2015'.

This occurs for the following where statements as well:

```
 where trunc(insert_date) like '5/1/2015%'
 where trunc(insert_date) = '5/1/2015'
```

I must be missing something simple here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRUNC - when applied to date - returns a date, so you should compare to a date:

```
  where trunc(insert_date) = date '2015-01-05'
```

This uses a DATE literal to create a date from an ISO date string (YYYY-MM-DD).

However, this will apply TRUNC() to every row in your table, thus hurting performance. A much better solution is to compare your column to an interval:

```
  where insert_date between date '2015-01-05' and date '2015-01-06'
```

**UPDATE**

As Wernfried pointed out, this will include '2015-01-06 00:00:00'. If that's a problem, you can either subtract a minimal timespan from the upper bound:

```
where insert_date between date '2015-01-05' 
  and date '2015-01-06' - interval '1' second
```

or use `<=` and `<` instead of `between` :

```
where date '2015-01-05' <= insert_date  
  and insert_date < date '2015-01-06'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55555/3)

Comment: Using the second statement outputs "literal does not match format string".

Comment: @antihero989, that's almost impossible. Probably you did a typo.

Comment: But the second statement includes `2015-01-06 00:00:00`. The first does not include this value. Better use `where insert_date >= date '2015-01-05' and insert_date < date '2015-01-06'`

Comment: I was getting "literal does not match format string" due to the time being included with the date so it wasn't a typo. "where insert_date >= date '2015-05-01' and insert_date < date '2015-05-02'" is working properly though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"LIKE" only works with character fields, not datetime fields.  Also, the date format for queries is YYYY-MM-DD.  To test for a date for a specific day:

```
insert_date BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-01:23:59:59'
```

Comment: Testing this outputs "literal does not match format string".

Comment: This will work only for some NLS settings and fail for others.

Comment: The "*date format for queries*" is **not** `YYYY-MM-DD` unless your NLS settings are configured for that. `'2015-05-01'` is a string literal that is implicitly converted to a date based on the current NLS settings for the session. ANSI date or timestamp literals,  use the ISO format, but they require the use of the keyword `date` or `timestamp`: `date '2015-05-01'` is a date literal.

Comment: In fact, I'd be very surprised if it worked for any NLS settings at all - this statement implicitly uses two different date formats (and BTW, as a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, the statement "the date format for queries is YYYY-MM-DD" is wrong).